# TS2339: Property 'focus' does not exist on type '{}'. with React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have a typescript code for JSX class

```
export class SearchForm extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {

  public inputRef: React.RefObject<{}>;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.inputRef = React.createRef()
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
      this.inputRef.current.focus()
      this.inputRef.current.select()
  ...
```

Now when I try to compile this code, I have a bunch of errors:

```
ERROR in ...
TS2339: Property 'className' does not exist on type '{}'.

ERROR in ...
TS2339: Property 'focus' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

What is an issue?

Comment: An alternative is `this.inputRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)`…

Answer (score 9):

The error is in type definition of the `inputRef: React.RefObject<{}>;`, which is default suggestion for autofixing the type issue.
Type `RefObject<{}>` is not assignable to type `RefObject<HTMLInputElement>`.
Type `{}` is missing the following properties from type `HTMLInputElement`: accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and more.

The correct row for `public inputRef: React.RefObject<{}>;` should be:

```
  public inputRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
```

And the the piece of the code will look like:

```
export class SearchForm extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {

  public inputRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.inputRef = React.createRef()
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
      this.inputRef.current.focus()
      this.inputRef.current.select()
  ...
```

Comment: Why `this.inputRef.current.select()`?

Comment: First, you don't need the constructor to create the ref. Just do it when declaring `inputRef`. Next, surround your code in `componentDidMount()` with `if (this.inputRef.current) { ... }` to make sure it's not null. Also read this https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-refs-with-typescript-a32d56c4d315